# Logback file inclusion with a wildcard

Tags: log4j, slf4j, logback

We have multiple plugins added to our application. Each plugin comes with its own logback_plugin.xml configuration file. We have to maintain the same in a specific folder. 
I can use the INCLUDE tag for inclusion of another configuration file from logback.xml file. Can we do it for multiple files, something like

```
<include file="src/main/resources/*.xml" />
```

than explicitly naming  a file, So that all the files are included. I tried the same but it ended up in an IOException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result by nesting the  tags.

I added the below include tag to the main logback.xml file

```
<include file="src/main/resources/plugins_logback.xml" />
```

Added file plugins_logback.xml at the above location which had an `<included>` element . All other plugins specific logback configuration files were included as a sub element as mentioned below.

```
<included>
  <include file="src/main/resources/plugin1_logback.xml"/>
  <include file="scr/main/resources/plugin2_logback.xml"/>
</included>
```

Logback configurator loads the entire configuration from all the files during startup.